# Как сделать проверку фильтрацию по не None. Django

Tags: django, orm

Нужно получить обьекты Product, в которых sales не Null

```
def get_queryset(self):        
        return Product.objects.prefetch_related('sales').filter(product.sales not Null)
```

Comment: `.exclude(sales=None)`

Comment: @andreymal ответьте на вопрос и пусть автор закроет его :)

Comment: @ZaArs мне лень